# admin user and password stolen

Tags: security, password, magento1.9.2.4

For a few weeks, my admin and user password are stolen.

I followed all the rules against brute force, but after a few days, after I restore the website with the old backup, I found a new admin user and password.

What is strange is that today I found the previous admin user and a impossible to decrypt password: 
'`39a5b5d9bb44e4d16227f7c71aa60af6:USi9sn2VLm3SssMLS8BS7QrJ2kQFRjvs`'

I have **1.9.2.4** version, including captcha on the backend login.

Please help me with some advice,

Comment: What service are you using to serve your website? Like Apache Or Nginx, etc... Check your `access_log` to see if you can find some odd requests or something, check which pages they're visiting. It could be a malicious or poorly made module that is letting them gain access into your site, which modules do you have installed if any?

Comment: Try https://www.magereport.com/ to see if you are missing a patch or two and report back with more info.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your site in [magereport](http://magereport.com). You will see if any patches are missed or your admin url is disclosed.

Basically, you should have custom admin url which can be accessed from your IP only. If you have followed the best practice of Magento security, these things are explained.

Like you said, you have followed all [instruction](https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing-new-update) for brute force, but still they are able to take control of your admin.

Most likely,

**I suspect few things:**

1. Your backed up site is also infected.
2. Some custom extensions have the vulnerability.
3. Intruder have installed "Magpleasure/Filesystem" extension, which allows to control remotely.
4. Your database is also infected

**Most of the time these files are infected**

1. Mage_Cms_IndexController
2. core/functions.php
3. lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
4. many more

**Check these links for more help**

1. https://magentary.com/kb/magento-recovery-shoplift-vulnerability/
2. https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/massive-magento-guruincsite-infection.html
3. https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/magento-shoplift-supee-5344-exploits-in-the-wild.html
4. **https://magento.com/security**

Comment: Good summary. Nice answer!

Comment: Thank you and Happy new year, For now, i installed the patch SUPEE-8788 for 1.9.2.4 and i set captcha on admin; for one week i don't have any issues, i hope to works well.